# In wireframe mode, Is there a way to show edges at the back and not only whats directly in front?

Tags: wireframe

If I go to wireframe mode, I only see whats directly in front of me and not the edges at the back or the ones of the objects inside unlike in edit mode. Is there a way to show them or do I just use edit mode?

Comment: If you want to see through your object just turn on x-ray mode. with option+z or alt+z

Comment: On the left of the Wireframe Shading button you have an X-Ray button.

Comment: ...or turn it _off_. It toggles, and is independent of the wireframe mode.